# Which statistical test should I use? 2 groups, different points in time, one group is independent, one dependent

Tags: r, anova

I was pretty sure my statistical knowledge was quite good, but I should probably re-evaluate myself.

I have a dataset, which consist of 2 groups, which have 3 points in time:

- treatment
- control

Ok, this is pretty straightforward, but:

- treatment group had always the same participants (repeated measures ANOVA)
- control group is completly independent between points in time (one
  way ANOVA)

How should I compare these 2 groups with each other? Simple t-test for every point in time? Within subjects is only possible with the treatment group, isn't it?

I would like to perform the analysis in R, do you have any suggestions for a specific package, function?

Comment: Maybe a paired t-test?

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate what, exactly, you want to test, so it doesn't seem to be answerable. What are your specific null and alternative hypotheses (i.e. written algebraically, not in words). What are your assumptions? You'll need your notation to be able to encompass all of the parameters involved.